# Conditional formatting, cell reference shifting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using Google Sheets to track tasks, each task is a single row, which can have a certain "Status" in of the cells.

I'm using conditional formatting, to highlight when a "Task" has a certain "Status"

Example:

Apply to range: "E2:E1000"
Format rules: "If text contain "Completed"
Highlight that cell.

The issues that I'm encountering on daily basis: Due to adding/deleting/sorting these rows, my conditional formatting range shifts. So the range of the example above currently shifted to "E4:E980".

Is there a way to imitate "indirect" function in conditional formatting, or any other way to make formatting range stay absolute?

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant to make it relative to something, right? (They are already absolute) Also how would you specify it if it were a formula on another sheet?

Comment: On the contrary, if I delete lets say rows 2 and 3, the range changes back to E2:E1000, if I paste them back, its back to E3, so they are relative. 

Another example, after few months working in the sheet, a simple B1:E850, now looks like this: "B1:E1,C9:E9,D13:E13,D16:D17,C17:C18,E17,C26:E28,C30:E35,B33,C37:E845,B42,B45:B845"

Please keep in mind, that this is not something that Im altering, this happens to conditional formatting on its own

Comment: You are 100% right. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Change the "Apply to" range from `E2:E1000` to `E:E`. It will self adjust to say `E1:E1000` (or to fill the entire column range, whatever number of rows you have); but it should hold up against insertions or deletions of rows.

Comment: Seems to be working for now, I will test this for a few days, thank you

Comment: Great. If this does address your concern, please take a moment to mark my post as "Best Answer." This allows contributors to see at a glance from the main dashboard which issues have been resolved, and it allows future site visitors like yourself to more quickly find relevant answers to their own similar questions.

Comment: Of course! As soon as I confirm that the solution is working, I will mark this as solved. I just need a few days to make sure of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, after working in the file for the rest of the day, today in the morning a checked the formatting rules, E:E (which converted to E1:E850) is now "E1:E6,E9:E844"

Comment: When you say you are "adding" rows, are you adding BLANK rows and then entering information into them? Or are you copying rows/data from some other sheet or source and pasting it in? It makes a difference. I'll explain once I know your answer.

Comment: Details:
Im not actually adding rows, Im using the ones that are already there. 
What I'm doing is: Cutting rows and pasting them into another sheet. Straight up deleting some rows.
But I'm never adding new ones, or pasting something from another sheet.

Comment: This is important information. But I still do not have a complete picture of your process (or your goal, for that matter). Right now, are you cutting data, pasting it somewhere else, and then coming back to delete the empty row you left in the source sheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229732/discussion-between-konata-and-erik-tyler).

Comment: I joined the chat shortly after you write your last comment, but you did not reply. Please read my entry in the chat and respond back here.

Comment: @Konata have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: This is a year and a half old. You didn't respond to my additional questions then, which is why I could not continue to help. It is clear that you are pasting information from somewhere else into the original sheet. If you do that with Ctrl-V or Paste, you bring the copied formatting with the copied data, and that will break CF rules. To paste without the formatting, use Ctrl-Alt-V ("Paste Special"). A small clipboard icon will appear lower right of the on-screen paste area. Click it and chose "Paste values only."